# bcrypt compare returning false when password contains numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm using [node-bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bcrypt) along with PostgreSQL (via [Sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com/) to hash and save passwords.

The user's password is hashed in a `beforeValidate` hook like so:

```
beforeValidate: function(user, model, cb) {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
          if ( err ) { throw err; }
          user.password = hash;
          cb(null, user);
        });
      }
```

The column on the User model in which the hash is stored is defined as:

```
password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
```

When a user is logging in (I'm using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication), the function looks like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    models.User.find({ username: username }).then(function(retrievedUser) {
      if ( !_.isEmpty(retrievedUser) ) {
        retrievedUser.verifyPassword(password, function(err, result) {
          if ( err || !result ) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
          } else {
            return done(null, retrievedUser);
          }
        });
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'User could not be found at that username.' });
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      return done(err);
    });
  }));
```

Which retrieves the user correctly.

And the comparison, defined here on the User model:

```
instanceMethods: {
      verifyPassword: function(password, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, cb);
      }
    }
```

The verification passes just fine if the password only contains letters and/or symbols. However, any passwords with numbers never pass the comparison. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the hash in the db is correct? Maybe you accidentally lowercased the password before creating the hash?

Comment: @loganfsmyth just double-checked to make sure this wasn't the problem, and it looks like uppercase letters actually work fine. The problem is just with symbols and numbers (edited original post)

Comment: Which module are you using?  There are a number of bcrypt implementations.

Comment: @AaronDufour I'm using the implementation linked in my original post, [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bcrypt). I believe it's the official node implementation?

Comment: Ah, the link blends in pretty well when I've already visited it.  Anything you have to install with npm is unofficial.  That author just happened to grab the `bcrypt` name first.  That said, that does appear to be the most commonly used one, which is a good indication.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `retrievedUser.password` instead of `retrievedUser.hash` ?

Comment: @DamianKrawczyk oops, I had fixed that locally but missed it when updating the question. Updated the question now to reflect the latest state of my project

Comment: are these chars encoded?

Comment: I do not think this is bcrypt related. I assume that your passwords for letters only are matching because of automatic type conversion in JS. It would be helpful if you could provide exact input you are giving to hash call in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, embarrassingly (and as some people suspected), this was completely unrelated to Bcrypt.

In my authentication function, I was attempting to fetch the appropriate user with the following:

```
models.User.find({ username: username })
```

However, the query should have been specified in a `where` field, like so:

```
models.User.find({
   where: { username: username }
})
```

This was causing the authentication method to always be comparing to the password for the first user in the database (returned by default when no `where` field is specified). Thus, it SEEMED to work because the first user's letters-only password always worked but no following passwords worked (in reality, even a letters-only password would have failed for other users).

Answer (score 2):

In your `beforeValidate` function you are passing in 10 as the salt you need to generate your salt, change that function to this

```
beforeValidate: function(user, model, cb) {
    var salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if ( err ) { throw err; }
      user.password = hash;
      cb(null, user);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I thought that may be it as well but the documention says:

"salt - [REQUIRED] - the salt to be used to hash the password. if specified as a number then a salt will be generated and used (see examples)."

Not to say that it is not causing the issue (I did not test it) but it appears to be allowed.